# Set a default value for an Orchard Content Field

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I am adding a `BooleanField` to a `WidgetPart` from a migration as follows:

```
ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("WidgetPart",
    builder => builder.WithField("DisplayInSubnav", fieldBuilder => fieldBuilder
        .OfType("BooleanField")
        .WithDisplayName("Display in Subnav")));
```

When it renders on the admin UI's Edit Widget page, the field's default value is null. **How can we set the BooleanField's default to true?**

I have tried to set the default from the `WidgetPartHandler` to no avail.

```
public class WidgetPartHandler : ContentHandler
{
    public WidgetPartHandler(IRepository<WidgetPartRecord> widgetsRepository) {

        OnInitializing<WidgetPart>((context, part) => 
            (part as dynamic).ShowInSubnav.Value = true);

        OnLoading<WidgetPart>((context, part) => 
            (part as dynamic).ShowInSubnav.Value = true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value is a setting of the field. Add `.WithSetting("BooleanFieldSettings.DefaultValue", "true")` to the field builder in the migration.

Comment: That is going to be sooooo helpful. Thank you, Bertrand the King. Hope to "see" you at the next steering committee meeting.